# MySQL foreach alternative for procedure

Tags: sql, mysql, stored-procedures, foreach

My problem is fairly simple. I have table `sets` that store product sets (more products looking like one on the outside - computer, mouse and keyboard for ex.) it's connected M:N using `sets_products` table to `products` table. Each product can have parameters (connected again M:N).

I have a procedure, that generates all parameters as string (for search cache - like 'hdd:120GB, LCD:1440:900, ..'), but now I need to loop through the set's products and call the procedure for each of them. I CAN'T DO IT IN PHP, because this is used in trigger.

I'd like to use something like this (pseudo SQL)

```
FOREACH(SELECT products_id FROM sets_products WHERE set_id = 1)
    generate_parameter_list(product_id,@result)
    @param = CONCAT(@param,",",@result);
END FOREACH;
```

Can this be done in MySQL or not?

Comment: Ah, i forgot the question itself - *Can this be done in MySQL or not?*

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Here's the [mysql reference for cursors](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cursors.html). So I'm guessing it's something like this:

```
  DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE products_id INT;
  DECLARE result varchar(4000);
  DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT products_id FROM sets_products WHERE set_id = 1;
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;

  OPEN cur1;

  REPEAT
    FETCH cur1 INTO products_id;
    IF NOT done THEN
      CALL generate_parameter_list(@product_id, @result);
      SET param = param + "," + result; -- not sure on this syntax
    END IF;
  UNTIL done END REPEAT;

  CLOSE cur1;

  -- now trim off the trailing , if desired
```

Comment: I needed to use CALL procedure_name and DECLARE every parameter used, but it worked. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You may also use [SQL LOOP](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/loop.html) syntax instead of REPEAT if you need more flexibility on leaving or continuing the loop.

Answer (score 14):

This can be done with MySQL, although it's highly unintuitive:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE p25 (OUT return_val INT)
BEGIN
  DECLARE a,b INT;
  DECLARE cur_1 CURSOR FOR SELECT s1 FROM t;
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND
  SET b = 1;
  OPEN cur_1;
  REPEAT
    FETCH cur_1 INTO a;
    UNTIL b = 1
  END REPEAT;
  CLOSE cur_1;
  SET return_val = a;
END;//
```

Check out this guide: [mysql-storedprocedures.pdf](https://web.archive.org/web/20130509230922/http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql-storedprocedures.pdf)

Comment: Intuitive and well written guide in your link!

Comment: I know it's old answer but still people (like me) are searching for that. PDF is no longer available but here I found nice explanation: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-cursor/