# Prepend table names on MySQL database export

Tags: mysql, export

Is it possible to prepend some text to all tables when exporting a mysql dump.

For example:  if the table is named `chapters` I want to prepend `old_` to it so it becomes `old_chapters`

Comment: Can you not just do a search and replace on the dump file?

Comment: The dump in question also includes content and is quite large (it stalls most text editors). Also the terms exist in content as well, which makes a simple replace quite tricky.

Comment: How about copying the relevant table and then ignoring the original table in the dump?

Comment: Should be a duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3326581/how-to-import-a-mysql-dump-while-renaming-some-tables-columns-and-not-importing

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the complexity of your schema, you may be able to accomplish this with a carefully crafted `sed` command that finds all of the table references and prepends the table names with "old_".

For example, this command will dump your schema and data and add the old_ prefix to the drop/create table statements as well as the lock/alter table and insert statements:

```
mysqldump your_schema | sed -e 's/DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `/DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `old_/' -e 's/CREATE TABLE `/CREATE TABLE `old_/' -e 's/INSERT INTO `/INSERT INTO `old_/' -e 's/LOCK TABLES `/LOCK TABLES `old_/' -e 's/ALTER TABLE `/ALTER TABLE `old_/'
```

However, that command will not add the table prefix for any of the following types of table references:

- Foreign Key constraints
- Views
- Triggers
- Stored routines

Comment: Foreign keys by adding: -e 's/REFERENCES `/REFERENCES `old_/'