# How to dump a subset of MySQL columns?

Tags: mysql

I'm aware of mysqldump's "--where" clause which allows dumping a selected subset of a table's rows, but is there a way of dumping only a subset of a MySQL table's columns? It appears like the best solution so far is to dump the table as a whole, and then do a SELECT/INSERT from that table into a newer one with the subset of columns I desire, as described here:

[How to import a mysql dump while renaming some tables/columns and not importing others at all?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3326581/how-to-import-a-mysql-dump-while-renaming-some-tables-columns-and-not-importing)

Comment: are you only interested in extracting data or would you like to use the dump for other purposes?

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for a [`SELECT INTO OUTFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select-into.html) rather than a  `mysqldump`

Comment: You're right, that does look like what I'm looking for--the drawback I see with this is that file is written to the remote DB's filesystem in the event that you're connected remotely. Is this true? I thought that part of the appeal of mysqldump is that you can run as a single bash command "mysqldump -h <remotehost> <database> <tablename> | mysql -h localhost" and write a remote table into your localhost DB.