# MySQL foreach loop

Tags: mysql, loops, database-cursor

I have to iterate each row in my table User in MySQL. 
I need to create a new row Address for each iteration in User with some conditions described below.

I have 3 tables:

```
User: id, stuff, id_person, email
Person: id, stuff, id_address
Address: id, email
```

I need to create a new row in Address if the User.id_person is NOT NULL and that person.id_address IS NULL.
I have to create the row with the same email that User.email.
I have to do that for each row in User.

I tried to use MySQL cursor's but I do not know how to use them very well.

How can I do that? Is there any other way instead of using cursor's for that?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I have just realized that I also have to update person.id_address with the id of the address' row I have just created.

Comment: Lookup INSERT ,,, FROM SELECT. If you can construct a SELECT statement that results in the "rows" needed to do the insert into Address, that will do the job without having to resort to a foreach loop.

Comment: can you post the code that you've tried, w/ the cursor? this should be a fairly easy task. if i'm analyzing your data right, i don't think an iteration is necessary, a simple `INSERT INTO` w/ conditionals should suffice.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

From what I can gather, the following should suffice, so long as the fields are what you have provided.

```
INSERT INTO Address (email)
  SELECT User.email
    FROM User JOIN person ON User.id_person = person.id
   WHERE person.id_address IS NULL
;
```

**EDIT (with Cursor)**

This should be pretty simple with a cursor, however I highly advise you familiarize yourself with these and the implications.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS _tmp_update_address;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE _tmp_update_address()
BEGIN
   DECLARE cursor_List_isdone BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE;
   DECLARE cur_userId, cur_personId INT;
   DECLARE cur_email VARCHAR(250) DEFAULT '';

   DECLARE cursor_List CURSOR FOR 
      SELECT User.id, person.id_address, User.email
      FROM User JOIN person ON User.id_person = person.id
      WHERE person.id_address IS NULL
    ;

   DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET cursor_List_isdone = TRUE;

   OPEN cursor_List;

   loop_List: LOOP
      FETCH cursor_List INTO cur_userId, cur_personId, cur_email;
      IF cursor_List_isdone THEN
         LEAVE loop_List;
      END IF;

      INSERT INTO Address (email) VALUES (cur_email);
      UPDATE person SET person.id_address = LAST_INSERT_ID()
         WHERE person.id = cur_personId;

   END LOOP loop_List;

   CLOSE cursor_List;
END

$$

DELIMITER ;

CALL _tmp_update_address();
```

Answer (score 4):

When I search "mysql foreach loop" this is what I found, and since I found a better alternative than the cursor for doing a foreach loop, here we are :

```sql
delimiter $$
create or replace procedure _tmp_procedure() begin
    for var_user in (
        select User.id, person.id_address, User.email
        from User join person on User.id_person = person.id
        where person.id_address is null
    ) do
        INSERT INTO Address (email) VALUES (var_user.email);
        UPDATE person SET person.id_address = LAST_INSERT_ID()
            WHERE person.id = var_user.id_person;
    end for;
end;
$$

call _tmp_procedure();
```

Comment: Syntax doesn't work with mysql.

Comment: Ow. My bad. I probably wrote it with a MariaDB syntax ( •~•)

Comment: im was here looking for a loop and I'm using mariadb and found only complex stuff, nice thank you very much u save me a lot of work and complex stuff :)

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to use a cursor for this.  Based on what you describe:

```
insert into address (address)
    select u.email
    from user u join
         person p
         on u.id_person = p.id;
```