# its possible do a loop with each row from query inside procedure mysql

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I need create a store-procedure in mysql but i have problem, i don't know if is possible that i can a loop with return rows from query

**this a tableOfExample**

```
--------------------+-------+------+
fecha               | cod   | Ucod |
--------------------+-------+------+
2020-11-10 00:20:50 | 24167 |    1 |
2020-11-10 00:20:24 | 24166 |    1 |
2020-11-08 03:01:29 | 24165 |    1 |
2020-11-08 01:18:21 | 24161 |    1 |
2020-11-07 20:26:59 | 24160 |    1 |
2020-11-06 20:55:09 | 24159 |    1 |
2020-11-06 20:51:58 | 24158 |    1 |
2020-11-06 20:49:27 | 24155 |  390 |
2020-11-06 20:28:40 | 24153 |    1 |
2020-11-06 20:22:50 | 24150 |    1 |
2020-11-06 18:18:57 | 24149 |    1 |
2020-11-06 15:14:27 | 24148 |   48 |
2020-11-06 14:55:44 | 24147 |  107 |
2020-11-06 14:52:22 | 24146 |  107 |
2020-11-06 14:50:48 | 24145 |  107 |
2020-11-06 14:29:31 | 24144 |    1 |
2020-11-06 13:20:33 | 24143 |    1 |
2020-11-05 22:00:37 | 24142 |    1 |
2020-11-05 14:58:00 | 24141 |  107 |
2020-11-05 14:57:06 | 24140 |  107 |
--------------------+-------+------+
```

**And my sql code**

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS testProc;
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE testProc(user int)
BEGIN

    -- DECLARE cursor_history CURSOR FOR SELECT * FROM tableOfExample WHERE uCod=user;
    SELECT @user:=uCod FROM tableOfExample WHERE uCod=user;
    SELECT @results:=FOUND_ROWS();

    IF @results > 0
        THEN
            -- wile doesn't work for my logic
            WHILE i < @results DO
                SET i := i + 1;
            END WHILE;
    END IF;
END //
DEMILMITER;
```

Thanks

Comment: post your code as text, highlight it and hit the {} button. Voilà! You will have your code as expected. There is no reason why this shouldn't be valid code

Comment: here is the solved https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49239885/mysql-foreach-loop